# Installing vlc 3.0 on Trusty through ppa still gives version 2.1.6

Tags: 14.04, ppa, vlc

How do I install vlc 3.0 on Ubuntu 14.04? I have tried:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:videolan/master-daily
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install vlc
```

But it says:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
vlc is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 18 not upgraded.
```

Doing `vlc --version` gives:

```
VLC media player 2.1.6 Rincewind (revision 2.1.6+git20160115+r54594+20+11~ubuntu14.04.1)
```

I have also tried to remove it first:

```
sudo apt-get remove vlc
sudo apt-get install vlc
```

But it just installs 2.1.6 version.

Comment: Trusty Tahr does not actually have a vlc package on this PPA...

Comment: You could try to install from source http://nightlies.videolan.org/build/source/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't install vlc-3 on ubuntu 14.04. you have to be upgrade either 14.10/15.04/15.10/16.04. Because vlc only have the 3.0.0~~git20160413+r64193+39~ubuntu for these version. Sorry to say you can't install vlc-3 in ubuntu 14.04 right now.